# Assign static IPs to tap clients in pfSense's OpenVPN server

Tags: firewall, openvpn, pfsense, tap

I am trying to set up a pfSense server with OpenVPN.

The OpenVPN will use the `tap` interface, `tun` clients are no option for us.

The LAN network is `10.0.0.0/24`, the pfSense machine is `10.0.0.10` and clients DHCP range is currently `10.0.0.200-10.0.0.220`.

The clients connect just fine with DHCP and can use the network.

I have tried to assign static IPs with the client specific overrides in pfSense. I used the commonly advised `ifconfig-push` command, but the clients I tested with(Windows 8 and Arch Linux) just don't take the IP assigned in their respective override. I've tried `ifconfig-push` with different arguments(client-IP + server, client-IP + subnet mask, ..).

If I leave the DHCP for the tap-interface on, clients will take an IP address from the client DHCP range, if I switch DHCP off clients don't get an IP at all. I have tried to push the static IP inside and outside of the DHCP range.

Is there any way to make the override work and force the assigned IP to the client? I would need this especially for access limitations with pfSense's firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some *deep* digging I found a [bug](https://redmine.pfsense.org/issues/1417) in pfSense's Redmine tracker. This states that the OpenVPN server is missing the `client-config-dir` variable.

Adding

```
mode server;client-config-dir /var/etc/openvpn-csc;
```

to the advanced server options as well as providing the client specific override

```
ifconfig-push [IP] [netmask]
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Some update from my experience:

Valid for pfsense 2.3.2

Missing option "client-config-dir" was fixed. now its good.

but now, by default, openvpn server config in pfsense has option **"username-as-common-name"**

So in client specific override in field "Common Name" try to write **username** instead of the **Common Name**.

if you have problems with assigning static IPs, try to inspect your openvpn server config in "/var/etc/openvpn/server1.conf" for that option.

P.S. ifconfig-push option remain the same

Answer (score 0):

I have two vpn servers configured, thus I had two folders under /var/etc/openvpn-csc

```
 /var/etc/openvpn-csc/server2
 /var/etc/openvpn-csc/server3
```

I am not sure why the index was from server2. Anyways after inspecting cat /var/etc/openvpn/server2.conf and server3.conf and figuring out to which each server folder belongs to, I added : `mode server;client-config-dir /var/etc/openvpn-csc/server2;` to the advanced server options as well as client specific override `ifconfig-push [IP] [netmask]`. After that I got the static IP.